# How to set minDate/maxDate of NgbDatePicker in main component for using the settings in all page?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

In my angular 4 I am using Ng-bootstrap (v1.1.0) I have multiple date pickers under multiple modules. I want to set maxDate configuration in all the location. My folder structure is as follows.

```
public.module.ts
public.component.ts

---- first.module.ts
---- first.component.ts
-------------- first-sub.component.ts
..............................
..............................

---- second.module.ts
----second.component.ts
-------second-sub.component.ts
..............................
..............................
```

I tried initializing NgbDatepickerConfig in the public.component.ts as below

```
    constructor(config: NgbDatepickerConfig) {
          config.maxDate = { "year": 2018, "month": 7, "day": 4} ;
    }
```

I am using the following code to display the calendar

```
<input type="text" id="selectDate" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'DATE_OF_INCIDENT' | translate}}" formControlName="selectDate"
                                        ngbDatepicker #selectedDate="ngbDatepicker" readonly>
```

Can you suggest a method so that we can configure the date settings at one place and can be used in all locations which uses Ngb DatePicker

Comment: Have you read the [API documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDatepickerConfig)? It says: *Configuration service for the NgbDatepicker component. You can inject this service, **typically in your root component**, and customize the values of its properties in order to provide default values for all the datepickers used in the application.* (emphasis mine)

Comment: JB Nitzet say that you must make a class NgbdDatepickerConfig, and declare in your appModule. see the plunker made by ngb-bootstrap http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview TIP:ng-bootstrap make a effort to actualize his page. In tab examples you can see examples, in each item, you can see a plunker

Comment: @Eliseo no, that's absolutely not what I said. Don't make me says what I didn't.

Comment: I tried giving max date to the configuration even in app.component.ts. But it is not working for ngb datepicker directive

Comment: Edit my comment (the link is bad) you must make a class NgbdDatepickerConfig, and declare in your appModule. see the plunker made by ngb-bootstrap https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/datepicker/demos/config/plnkr.html TIP:ng-bootstrap make a effort to actualize his page. In tab examples you can see examples, in each item, you can see a plunker

Comment: @Eliseo no, you must not do that. You must do what the api doc says, that's all. Note: I wrote this demo, and I wrote the NgbDatepickerConfig service, and I wrote this documentation.

Comment: @vivekkurien post a complete minimal example, in a stackblitz, reproducing the issue.

Comment: @Eliseo I saw the link but its uses <ngb-datepicker [(ngModel)]="model"></ngb-datepicker> but I am using directive instead. You can see my html content above.

Comment: must be work with Reactive Form too

Comment: @JBNizet I will update the link with the code.

Answer (score 8):

must be using the NgbModule and  FormsModule

```
this.minDate = { year: 1985, month: 1, day: 1 };
this.maxDate={year:new Date().getFullYear(),month: 1, day: 1}
this.startDate = { year: 1988, month: 1, day: 1 };
```

```
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" placement="top-left" 
     [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" [startDate]="startDate" name="dateOfBirth" 
     id="dateOfBirth" [(ngModel)]="dateOfBirth" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" 
     (click)="d.toggle()">
```

Answer (score 4):

For me it works as described in docs:

```
            <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="birthDate" placeholder="Date of Birth"
                     id="inputDateOfBirth" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"
                     [minDate]="{year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1}">
```

Docs: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#limiting-dates